# How to determine a integer in a set of a map in c++?

Tags: c++

Given a map:

```
std::map< int, std::set<int> > result;
```

How can I know whether a certain integer, let's say, 3, in the value of set , when the key is 1, i.e. {1, {3,x,x..}} exists in the result?

Answer (score 4):

```
if (result[1].count(3))
{
    std::cout << "3 exists!" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "3 doesn't exist" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Provided that the key `1` exists in the map:

```
if(result[1].find(3) != result[1].end()) {
  // key exists
} else {
  // key doesn't exist
}
```